# C++ floats and doubles on different platforms/architectures

Tags: c++, floating-point, cpu-architecture, platform

For context, I'm developing a library for Arduino to transfer data packets over LoRa receivers.

Question I'm having is, the library is placing the raw bits from floats and doubles into `uint8_t` arrays, sending them and then tranferring them back into floats and doubles.

This of course works when the compiler, platform and architecture is the same, but will I run into problems when unpacking them and simply copying the data straight to a float on other platforms like C++ on Windows or Linux?

I could of course use integers and have some factor to retain decimal places but this adds complexity I'd rather somehow work around.

Comment: Endianness is something you need to worry about, all modern systems with hardware FPUs use IEEE 754 binary32 floats and binary64 doubles.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: When in doubt formatted text is the great equalizer. It sounds slow and stupid, but it works and often it's fast enough.

Comment: Have the sender convert outgoing floats from its native format into a standardized format, and then put that standard format into your byte array. Have the receiver convert incoming floats from the received bytes in standard format into its native format. If the native and transmitted formats happen to be the same, so be it, but don't rely on that, except as an implementation optimization.  Same goes for integers, text, any multi-byte data type. Don't send data in their raw format, standardize them.

Comment: If you decide to use formatted text, consider the `"%a"` `printf` format. It generates hexadecimal output and doesn't lose any precision (assuming the floating-point radix is a power of 2, which is nearly certain).

Comment: You could simply have a struct of two integer values consisting of the decimal portion of the floating point, and the fractional portion of the floating point value, and send that instead of the raw floating point value.  This of course assumes your floating point values fall within the range of an integer.  Then the sender knows exactly what they're getting and will handle it accordingly.

Comment: I was going to mention `std::hexfloat`, then I forgot. Probably a good thing. I'm not sure if it works in C++ yet or not.

Comment: In your case the standardisation might simply look like: `data is transferred as IEEE754, 32 or 64 bits respectively, little endian`. That should match 99.9% (personal estimate) of modern hardware... If there's any non-matching HW available, then, well, for this platform special handling is necessary...

Comment: How comes you got floating point data at all? There are exceptions, but usually you are better off with fixed point arithmetics anyway, never using floating point with all its trouble around rounding issues at all. Maybe you can convert your algorithms accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

If your implementation uses ieee754 floating point numbers, and also has unsigned 32 and 64 bit integers, then most likely there is a one-to-one correspondence between float and 32 bit integers, and between double and 64 bit integers. And that applies to exactly 100% of implementations that I’ve used in the last ten years. (Long double is more variable).

So you can move a float into a 32 bit unsigned int, store the four bytes in some fixed order by storing x>>24, x>>16, x>>8 and x as bytes in any fixed order, and read them back in the same order. Same for double with 64 bit.

Alternatively, you store the numbers as text as JSON does.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply memcpy floats and double, you'll be OK on the same platform, regardless of the compiler.

As soon as you try to memcpy structs or classes, you'll need the same compiler version and settings. This is a huge can of worm. Just check the amount of question around padding on this site. It will come back and bite you in the back side.

For all practical purposes, bite the bullet now, convert to integers or use a serialization toolkit (json, protobuf, etc..). If you worry about performance, once you have the serialization as integers or text working, add an optional memcpy mode, where the handshake verifies compatibility by exchanging a message, and then pick either method.

Comment: *you'll need the same compiler version and settings.* -- POD structs that are byte-aligned are safe to send.